# add parameter to part of URL and keeping rest of URL in tact

Tags: jquery, url

On the following page, and others like it, where the "Donate" link is I need to add (? or &) `pw_id=2461`.

Page referenced:

```
http://fundraising.stjude.org/site/TR/Heroes/Heroes?px=2373525&pg=personal&fr_id=10850
```

Since the href doesn't have an id or class to it I could target it using `.support_participant a` and if you look at the URL for the donate link, it is:

```
/site/Donation2?df_id=2300&PROXY_ID=2373525&PROXY_TYPE=20&FR_ID=10850
```

From that URL, the following parameters will be consistent across these type pages where I want to modify this URL: `df_id`, `proxy_type` and `fr_id`.

To see why I need to add this parameter, you can see the difference of the donation form by going to the donate link with the parameter added: URL with parameter:

```
/site/Donation2?df_id=2300&PROXY_ID=2373525&PROXY_TYPE=20&FR_ID=10850&pw_id=2461
```

I'm a newbie when it comes to jquery although I am enjoying learning so any patience with me would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a fairly well-addressed question. Search for more.

Comment: Sorry - got the answer to my own question after posting. Here's what worked for me:

    <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
      var _href = jQuery(".support_participant a").attr("href");
      jQuery(".support_participant a").attr("href", _href + '&pw_id=2461');
     });
    </script>

Comment: Code doesn't go in comments. Please provide an answer below or delete the question. Thanks!